# how to use an element of a character vector as a symbol argument to a function using non-standard evaluation := operator

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a character vector of variable names as symbolic arguments.

Here is some data taken from the "fertility" dataset in the `questionr` package. The important thing is that it includes some columns of labelled data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(labelled)

df <- structure(list(id_woman = structure(c(391, 1643, 85, 881, 1981, 
                                            1072, 1978, 1607, 738), label = "Woman Id", 
                                          format.spss = "F8.0"), 
                     weight = structure(c(1.80315, 1.80315, 1.80315, 1.80315, 
                                          1.80315, 0.997934, 0.997934, 0.997934, 0.192455), 
                                        label = "Sample weight", format.spss = "F8.2"), 
                     residency = structure(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                                           label = "Urban / rural residency", 
                                           labels = c(urban = 1, rural = 2), 
                                           class = "haven_labelled"), 
                     region = structure(c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3), label = "Region", 
                                        labels = c(North = 1, East = 2, South = 3, West = 4),
                                        class = "haven_labelled")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This function simply takes a variable name and converts it from labelled data to a factor.

```
my.func <- function(var){
  df %>%
    mutate({{var}} := to_factor({{var}}))
}
```

Both of these lines work.

```
my.func(residency)
my.func("residency")
```

They return this:

```
  id_woman weight residency    region
     <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>     <dbl+lbl>
1      391  1.80  rural     4 [West] 
2     1643  1.80  rural     4 [West] 
3       85  1.80  rural     4 [West] 
4      881  1.80  rural     4 [West] 
5     1981  1.80  rural     4 [West] 
6     1072  0.998 rural     3 [South]
7     1978  0.998 rural     3 [South]
8     1607  0.998 rural     3 [South]
9      738  0.192 rural     3 [South]
```

The trouble comes if I try to provide the variable name as part of a vector, like this:

```
var.names <- c("residency", "region")

my.func(var.names[1])
 Error: The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

I tried this, but it also failed.

```
my.func(rlang::sym(var.names[1]))
 Error: The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, we have to evaluate (`!!`)

```
my.func(!!var.names[1])
# A tibble: 9 x 4
#  id_woman weight residency    region
#     <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>     <dbl+lbl>
#1      391  1.80  residency 4 [West] 
#2     1643  1.80  residency 4 [West] 
#3       85  1.80  residency 4 [West] 
#4      881  1.80  residency 4 [West] 
#5     1981  1.80  residency 4 [West] 
#6     1072  0.998 residency 3 [South]
#7     1978  0.998 residency 3 [South]
#8     1607  0.998 residency 3 [South]
#9      738  0.192 residency 3 [South]
```